# I have to perform set union and set difference on dataframe of different size which is being read in chunks

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have 4 data frames a,b,c,d

All being read from MySQL table in chunks .

I have to perform union operation on dataframe:
x = a U b and  y = c U d and then 
z  = x - y

I am not able to think of how to iterate them in chunks , I can't zip as there would be loss if size of one chunk is less than the other .

How should I approach this problem . 
 Say all a,b,c,d have one col called ids.

Need to perform aUb - cUd on chunks of data read from MySQL table .

Comment: Can you refer this link to perform set operations in dataframes : https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/11/set-operations-applied-pandas-dataframes.html

Comment: its not what i need , my question is more about iterating dataframes of diffrent size in chunks withing same iteration